# Set and unset default ggplot colors within function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working on a custom theme function. As part of this function, there will be several palette choices that can be applied to different scales. However, I wish to set a default palette if none is specified. I would only like to set this palette when the function is called and, if the function is not called, use ggplot's default. I tried setting it within the fill arguments, but if a non-discrete scale is supplied, ggplot gives an error. Likewise, if I set a gradient palette in the arguments, errors also appear.

In the below function, I use `options(ggplot2.discrete.fill = rep(pal,3))` to set the palette in the beginning of the function. I use `options(ggplot2.discrete.fill = scale_fill_hue)` at the end to reset to the default ggplot palette, however, this is not respected.

```
pal = c("#F37321", "#8DC63F", "#13B5EA", "#9B5BA5", "#009F93", "#77787B")


mytheme <- function(fill = NULL, name = waiver(),
                    sequential = NULL){
  
  # set default if no palette is specified
  options(ggplot2.discrete.fill = rep(pal,3))
  
  # set custom fill arguments
  # fill ----
  scale_fill_custom <- function(fill, name=name, ...) {
    scale_fill_manual(values=fill, name, ...)}
  
  # gradient fill
  scale_fill_gradientn_custom <- function(sequential, name=name, ...){
    scale_fill_gradientn(colors=sequential, name=name, ...)
  }
  
  # theme ----
  themer <- function() {
    amp <- theme_minimal()
  }
  
  # output of function ----
  theme_object <- list(
    if(is.null(fill)) { NULL } else { scale_fill_custom(fill, name, na_color) },
    if(is.null(sequential)) { NULL } else {
      scale_fill_gradientn_custom(sequential, name) },
    themer())
  
  
  return(theme_object)

  # return to ggplot default
  options(ggplot2.discrete.fill = scale_fill_hue)
  
  
}
```

The following shows the correct colors:

```
mtcars %>%
  slice(1:10) %>%
  rownames_to_column("mfg") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=mpg, y=reorder(mfg, mpg), fill=as.factor(mpg)))+
  geom_col()+
  mytheme()
```

I would expect the following to show the default ggplot colors

```
mtcars %>%
  slice(1:10) %>%
  rownames_to_column("mfg") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=mpg, y=reorder(mfg, mpg), fill=as.factor(mpg)))+
  geom_col()
  # note - no mytheme() call
```

Any idea how to implement this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function doesn't work as expected because it never get to final `options()` - the `return()` is the last line of code run

```
  ...
  return(theme_object) ## last line executed

  # return to ggplot default
  options(ggplot2.discrete.fill = scale_fill_hue)
}
```

Instead, when you set the options, get the current value, and set it to revert when the function exits

```
  # set default if no palette is specified
  old <- options(ggplot2.discrete.fill = rep(pal,3))
  on.exit(options(ggplot2.discrete.fill = old$ggplot2.discrete.fill))
```

This will now reset the options when the function exits. However another problem is created, in that the options are required when the plot is printed, so the colours will be changed and changed back to the original before printing. A different approach is need.

I would simply set the default colours in the functions arguments